# CakePHP 2.4.4 How can I sort a multi-dimensional array with Hash::sort by string keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cakephp

I don't understand the docs regarding the [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) 'path', so I've had no luck. I'm trying to sort each layer alphabetically:

```
array(
'music' => array(
    'genre' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Dubstep',
        (int) 1 => 'Blues',
        (int) 2 => 'Classical'
    ),
    'instrument' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Guitar (Electric)',
        (int) 1 => 'Bassoon',
        (int) 2 => 'Harmonica (Diatonic)'
    ),
'anotherLot' => array(
```

I need to sort the first later of arrays by key, then the second later in each by key, and the third by the values, so I imagine the two deeper layers would be done with a  nested foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CakePHP's Hash class, but here is a plain PHP solution:

```
ksort($data); // sort main array by keys

foreach ($data as &$outer)
{
    ksort($outer); // sort next layer by keys
    foreach($outer as &$inner) 
    {
        asort($inner); // sort inner arrays by values
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if Hash::sort can do any better. I used natcasesort() instead of asort() for natural, case-insensitive ordering.